# Date conversion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a datetime column  I want to retrieve the date in hh:mm:ss where hours is 12hour.

I have tried the following.

```
 convert(varchar(10), t2.CSM_START_TIME,108),
 convert(varchar(2),datepart(hour,t2.CSM_START_TIME))
    +':'+convert(varchar(2),datepart(mm,t2.CSM_START_TIME))
    +':'+convert(varchar(2), datepart(SECOND,t2.CSM_START_TIME))  
    as START_TIME
```

Comment: And what was the outcome of your attempt(s)?

Comment: What format did you expect and what format did you get? Can you show what you got and how it's wrong? And why don't you format this at the presentation layer? So, so, so much easier.

Comment: Do you really want hh:mm:ss with no AM/PM? So you'll have no idea if 11:34:25 is AM or PM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20),GETDATE(),22),11));
```

Result:

```
11:40:15 PM
```

Or if you really don't want the AM/PM (which I don't understand):

```
SELECT LTRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), GETDATE(),22),11),8));
```

Result:

```
11:40:15
```

Much, much, much better to format this at the client. For example, if you are using C#, look at [`.Format()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp) and [`.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp). Don't make SQL Server do your dirty presentation work, especially when you have [much more flexible features in a more powerful language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This got me what I wanted.

,substring(convert(varchar(40), t2.CSM_START_TIME,109),12,9)+' '+substring(convert(varchar(40), t2.CSM_START_TIME,109),25,2)

Answer (score -1):

you should try this

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%h:%i %p')
```

or you will find more here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp.